# Module.export a 'default' function

Tags: node.js

I want to write a module that exports a default function and a list of properties (they are functions too).
Basically this module will allows this usage consumer-side:

```
let db_connection = fake_database_connection_instance()
let db = require('./db.js')(db_connection)
db.find({id:1})
```

So the default function should only pass the database connection instance to the module.
This is the not working code

```
module.exports = {
    //init should go away and replaced by a 'default' function when this module is called
    init: function (connection) {
        this.connection= connection;
        return this;
    },
    find: function (query) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            this.connection.find(query, function (err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                return resolve(docs);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I want to avoid the `new` keyword (consumer-side), so I have to remove those `this`, I know. The problem here are 2:

- how to export a default function called on `require('./db.js')()` and other functions e.g. `require('./db.js').find()`?
- how pass the connection instance from the default function to `find()`?

**EDIT** following the @Igor Raush ES6 Class solution I wrote this, but still `db is not defined`

```
class DB {
    constructor(db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
    find(query) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            this.db.find(query, function (err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                return resolve(docs);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In the updated code, `this` **refers** to the scope created by `Promise` function, not to the instance of your `DB`. You need to remember `DB.this` to use it in another scope.

Comment: that's not very 'classy' (in sense of OOP :) ).  thanks anyway

Comment: yes, even with syntactic sugar added in ES6, it's still just javascript:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a class and export an instance factory function.

```
// db.js
function DB(connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}

DB.prototype.find = function find(query) {
    let connection = this.connection;
    // ...
}

// export instance factory function
module.exports = function (connection) { return new DB(connection); };
```

or, if you're in an ES6 environment,

```
// db.js
class DB {
    constructor(connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    find(query) {
        let connection = this.connection;
        // ...
    }
}

// export instance factory function
module.exports = connection => new DB(connection);
```

Then you can do

```
let db = require('./db')(db_connection);
db.find({ id: 1 });
```

If you'd like to enforce the singleton pattern (only one `DB` instance can exist), lazily create a module-local instance and return the reference on subsequent calls:

```
let _instance = null;
module.exports = connection => {
    // return existing instance, or create a new one
    return _instance || (_instance = new DB(connection));
}
```

Comment: may I ask why you use `let connection = this.connection` in `find()`? I tried to refer straight to `this.connection` without declaring a new variable in my Promise but doesn't work, yours work, where the context changes in this example?

Comment: @alfredopacino, `this` inside the promise executor function refers to the global object, not to the `DB` instance as you expect. You can either keep a local reference to the `connection` object like I've done, or use an arrow function as the promise executor to preserve the lexical scope of `this`, in which case it _will_ refer to the `DB` instance inside the executor.

Comment: @alfredo, can you please provide the full code you're testing? I've just tested my implementation with a promise using an arrow function executor, it works fine for me.

Comment: FWIW, the code you edited into your question looks good to me, so the problem must lie somewhere else. Please also provide the full error stack.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a default function to `module.exports` and use an external variable `_conn` to store the connection:

```
let _conn;

module.exports = (connection) => {
  _conn = connection;
};
```

After that you could add `find` function to `module.exports` object:

```
module.exports.find = (query) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    _conn.find(query, function(err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(docs);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, except that forgetting to invoke the "initializer" function will cause the module-local `_conn` to be undefined in all other exported functions.

Comment: @IgorRaush the same problem is in your examples:), any module will not work the way you expected, if you forget to pass the required parameters.

Comment: Fair enough, although I don't export the `find()`, etc. functions at all, so if you do `let db = require('./db')` instead of `require('./db')(db_connection)`, it will be apparent that you are working with the wrong object (`db.find` will be undefined). In any case, I would also use your implementation, but I'd include a check in each exported function which asserts the presence of `_conn` before proceeding.

Comment: @IgorRaush not sure that adding assertion in each exported function is a good idea. If the connection is undefined (`db` was required without `connection` obj) the app will be terminated anyway, missing db connection is a critical error. So, this possible bug, will be fixed only once, but in the case of assertion, it will be executed every time when the function is called - extra expenses.